# В чем недостатки Firebase Anonymous Authentication по сравнению с другими способами аутентификации?

Tags: android, auth, firebase-database, платежи

Интересуют мобильные платформы (android). Если приложению предназначено продаваться, [анонимный пользователь](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth?utm_source=studio) ведь не оплатит покупку?  Имеет ли смысл тогда его анонимно регистрировать?

Comment: Если покупки через гугл-плей идут, то привязываются они к акку гугла. Т.е. не важно как и вообще залогинен ли юзер.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: то есть Google Play при оплате будет над приложением и пользователем? Значит имеет смысл и так регистрировать. Не зря задал я вопрос. Спасибо Вам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если покупки через гугл-плей идут, то привязываются они к акку гугла. Т.е. не важно как и вообще залогинен ли юзер

Comment: Интересно, анонимная регистрация на практике явно пользователю не предлагается, как это [продемонстрировали](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/AnonymousAuthActivity.java) в официальном мануале? Проводить её внутри "не спрашивая пользователя"?

Comment: @TimurVI, если в правилах FireBase стоит запрет на чтение/запись для неавторизованных то да - можно втихую анонимно авторизовать. Но, если потом юзер захочет таки авторизоваться, то придётся ему прописать логику перезаписи данных/добавления другого способа входа. В общем тут всё от задач ваших зависит